# Delphi KBMMemtable filter speed problem

Tags: delphi, filter

Hi I am using KBmmemtable in a small project and come across a small speed issue i cannot seem to fix.

Basically I have a field in the table which has a boolean value, the table has about 100 records in it. If I itterate though the records in the table setting the value of the field to true it does it very quickly, however if I set a filter on the table and then itterate through the filtered records it takes about 10 times longer even though there could only be 10 records to iteerate through.

Anyone got any ideas

The code I am using is

```
DM1.DS1.Enabled := False;
  with DM1.DS1.DataSet do begin
    First;
    while not Eof do begin
      edit;
      Fields[18].AsBoolean := TickState;
//      FieldByName('Selected').AsBoolean := TickState;
      post;
      next;
    end;
  end;
DM1.DS1.Enabled := true;
```

I do have an index on the field, I have also tried it without an index

thanks

colin

Comment: I use kbmMemTable a lot and i never had this behaviour, at least not so extreme. Is there an index active for the filtered field? Do you have visual controls attached to the table? What do you do with the records during interation? Maybe you can give us some code?

Comment: Just guessing: are you using `RecordCount` in a loop somewhere? It seems that each time you access this property the dataset will [iterate through all records](http://www.mestdagh.biz/kbm/mt/faq/MemTable.html#RecordCount17C) and evaluate the filter expression for each.

Comment: @Tondrej Tried using while instead but does the same.

Comment: Did you try to use the DisableControls, DisableEvents and DisableMasterDetail methods before browsing the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to use a filter on a kbmMemTable and make it work really fast...

Set kbmmem.Filtered:=true;

and dont use the Filter property, instead use the OnFilter Event...

```
procedure Tform1.kbmmemFilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept:=Fields[18].AsBoolean;
  // when you iter your table you would see only thouse rows having "true" 
  //  on the field "Selected"
end;
```

and yes dont forget to DisableControls before the while...

```
  with kbmMem do
  try
    DisableControls;
    Filtered:=true;
    First;
    while not eof do
    begin
      // do your stuff here
      Next;
    end;
  finally
    EnableControls;
  end;
```

Comment: @Cesar what exactly does the disable controls do? is it the same as disabling the datasource?

Comment: @cesar does it make a difference using fieldbyname or should I use fields[fieldno] thanks

Comment: @user435406 DisableControls prevents the db aware controls from reading the dataset, (dbGrids, dbEdits,...) so iterating through the dataset would be faster. @Andreas posted this in his answer.

Comment: @user435406 Fields[N] is faster than FieldByName('field') because the last has to find the field everytime it's used. But sometimes it's hard to maintain Fields[N] because you might have a lot of fields and inserting a field on the table or in the sql would result on changing a lot of code. I use Fields[] much more than FieldByName

Comment: You can give Filds a name and create a variable for fields. (right click on the table, insert field) So you don't have to deal with the field-index, which also can easily change!

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion for the loop, it should not take any longer than with an unfiltered kbmMemTable:

```
with kbmMemTable do
begin
  First;
  while not EOF do
  begin
    //do something, but don't change the position of the record-pointer!
    //if you do some writing to the record, be sure to  
    // enable "AutoReposition" in your kbmMemTable
    Next;
  end;
end;
```

Disabling the DataSource is not such a good option. Every Component attached to the DataSource is then "empty" and must be refreshed. You get a lot of problems if you use recursion or more than one "disabling" of a DataSource. Same, when you enable the DataSet. With DisableControls you signal all the attached components, that they must not update data. With EnableControls, this condition is ended and the controls are refreshed. Another advantage is, that there is a counter incremented with every DisableControls and decremented with every EnableControls. So you can call this multiple times (for example in an recursion) and only the last call of EnableControls finally enables the controls.

Comment: @Adreas I do not have an Autoreposition property?

Comment: Which version of kbmMemTable do you use?

Comment: V6.2, Although I am now going to upgrade to 7.x

Comment: There is for sure a property called AutoReposition, i checked it in the source. Set this to TRUE and then the record-pointer is not changed after a "post".